# Alternative way to implement the drag and drop on IFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a backend project that involves:
1. showing the frontend design
2. allowing users to drag and drop additional elements into pre-defined blocks on this frontend design

The plan was to within the backend display the frontend in an iframe while the elements will be out of the iframe of course, then allow users to drag and drop onto the content inside the iframe. However, we seem to run into issues with drag and drop into iframe.

I wonder if there is any alternative way? I believe some must have run into this issue before because this type of implementation is quite usual these days.

Comment: You have given other html as src for iframe right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you please re-phrase? Also, I think I may have a solution with using offset for the iframe (I need to calculate the distant from the iframe to the top of the window and offset with that)

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this?